# Correctly releasing reference-counted ByteBuf objects in netty 4.1

Tags: java, netty, nio

So, we are currently in the process of upgrading netty 3.x to netty 4.1 in our MQTT-based messaging backend. In our application, we use a custom MQTT message decoder and encoder.

For our decoder, I am currently using a [ByteToMessageDecoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html) as follows:

```
public class MqttMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        if (in.readableBytes() < 2) {
            return;
        }

        .....
        .....
        .....

        byte[] data = new byte[msglength];
        in.resetReaderIndex();
        in.readBytes(data);
        MessageInputStream mis = new MessageInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        Message msg = mis.readMessage();
        out.add(msg);
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(in);
    }
}
```

where `Message` is our custom object, that is passed to the next `ChannelHandler`'s `channelRead()`. As you can see, I am done with the incoming `ByteBuf` object `in` as soon as I create a `Message` object from it. So, since `ByteBuf` is reference-counted in netty, is it correct that I need to release the `in` object here by calling `ReferenceCountUtil.release(in)`? Ideally, this seems right according to the [doc](http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#inbound-messages). However, when I do this, I seem to be facing the exception:

```
Wed May 24 io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline:? WARN netty-workers-7 An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: com.bsb.hike.mqtt.MqttMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved() has thrown an exception.
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:631) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.destroyDown(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:867) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$300(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:45) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$9.run(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:874) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:339) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:374) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
Caused by: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:111) ~[netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:217) ~[netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:626) [netty-all-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

This tells me that when the child channel is closed, all the handlers in the pipeline are removed one after another. When this decoder handler is closed, we are explicitly releasing the `ByteBuf` attached to this decoder  which results in the `IllegalReferenceCountException` exception, when the method below is called.

This is the `AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf#release`:

```
@Override
    public boolean release() {
        for (;;) {
            int refCnt = this.refCnt;
            if (refCnt == 0) {
                throw new IllegalReferenceCountException(0, -1);
            }

            if (refCntUpdater.compareAndSet(this, refCnt, refCnt - 1)) {
                if (refCnt == 1) {
                    deallocate();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to release the `ByteBuf` objects then, to not encounter this issue?

I am using the `PooledByteBufAllocator` -

```
new ServerBootstrap().childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
```

Please let me know if you need any more info regarding the configuration.

---

**EDIT**:

As an add-on to Ferrybig's answer, the `ByteToMessageDecoder#channelRead` handles the releasing of the incoming `ByteBuf`s by itself. See the `finally` block -

```
@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            CodecOutputList out = CodecOutputList.newInstance();
            try {
                ByteBuf data = (ByteBuf) msg;
                first = cumulation == null;
                if (first) {
                    cumulation = data;
                } else {
                    cumulation = cumulator.cumulate(ctx.alloc(), cumulation, data);
                }
                callDecode(ctx, cumulation, out);
            } catch (DecoderException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new DecoderException(t);
            } finally {
                if (cumulation != null && !cumulation.isReadable()) {
                    numReads = 0;
                    cumulation.release();
                    cumulation = null;
                } else if (++ numReads >= discardAfterReads) {
                    // We did enough reads already try to discard some bytes so we not risk to see a OOME.
                    // See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4275
                    numReads = 0;
                    discardSomeReadBytes();
                }

                int size = out.size();
                decodeWasNull = !out.insertSinceRecycled();
                fireChannelRead(ctx, out, size);
                out.recycle();
            }
        } else {
            ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
        }
    }
```

If the inbound `ByteBuf` is being transferred to the next channel handler down the pipeline, the reference count of this `ByteBuf` is increased through `ByteBuf#retain` and so if the next handler after your decoder is your business handler (which is typically the case), you need to release that `ByteBuf` object there to avoid any memory leaks. This is also mentioned in the [docs](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#bytebuf-is-always-reference-counted) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all handlers require the passed in bytebuf to be destroyed. `ByteToMessageDecoder` is one of them.

The reason for this is that this handler collects multiple incoming bytebufs, and exposes them to your application as 1 continuous stream of bytes, for the ease of coding, and not needing to handle these chunks yourself

Remember that you still need to manually release any bytebufs your create by either using `readBytes` or `readSlice`, as stated by the javadoc.

Comment: You mean ByteToMessageDecoder requires or does not require to release ByteBufs?

Comment: @peter.petrov It does not require releasing.

Answer (score 2):

@Ferrybig his answer is good enough.

Here I want to add some simple convention dealing with ByteBuf releasing.

When you have a InboundHandler like this:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
ByteBuf buf = ByteBuf(msg)
...
// no fireChannelRead()
}
```

since you intercept the InboundHandler after it(if it had), and no one is taking care of the `ByteBuf` object, you need to release it manually.

you can also call fireChannelRead(). Netty add a tail handler to release the `ByteBuf` for you by default. So you do not need to release it after calling fireChannelRead().

If my answer has any problem, please tell me.